# x-paypal-authorization header with express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, user-permissions

How to process express checkout method using with tockenSecret and responseToken ?

Which call should I use? Please help

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to use REST APIs to process PayPal payments. Below is a link to a brief overview of the process for creating and executing PayPal payments.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

You can also try some interactive tests in PayPal's API playground:
https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal?interactive=ON&env=sandbox